# Apache 2.4 Block Requests Without User-Agent

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, user-agent

My goal is to simply block requests that don't have a User-Agent header set.  From [Apache's docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), this should be dead simple.  What I've been attempting to use (in a VirtualHost section) is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$    
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I'm testing this with `curl` using the following (with the domain name changed):

`curl -v --http1.1  https://example.com/ > /dev/null`

and the headers sent for this are:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

`curl -v --http1.1  --user-agent "" https://example.com/ > /dev/null`

while the headers sent for this are:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
```

I'm seeing exactly what I want to see sent in both cases.

No matter what I do, Apache just happily returns a 200 for both.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, Apache server variables are prefixed by a `%`, not `$`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$    
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```